# Web URL Filter implementation

Tags: c, http, https, proxy-server, webfiltering

I have received a task/project from my professor to build a solution for Web URL filtering. Now this being a very open-ended problem statement to work with, I had multiple ways to approach it. One way is to do the blocking on the client side itself. So, to do that, I first chose an approach of performing a reset attack on my own computer's TCP connection. This way I shall be able to terminate the TCP connection between the blocked IP/URL server and the client's computer. Another approach I could think of was to deploy a proxy server in the middle and sniff all the requests before the data packets manage to reach the blocked host server. This again is a valid approach, however, I am not very sure for how to approach it. I am a novice in the networks domain. Could someone guide me how to proceed from here? I need to implement it for HTTPS as well, however, things complicate with encryption and stuff.

Following is my current implementation of proxy-server approach but just for HTTP:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PROXY_PORT 8080
#define BLACKLISTED_URL "example.net"

void handle_client(int client_socket) {
    char request[4096];
    ssize_t bytes_received;

    // Receive the client's request
    bytes_received = recv(client_socket, request, sizeof(request), 0);

    // printf("Received request: %s\n", request);

    if (bytes_received < 0) {
        perror("Error receiving request");
        return;
    }

    // Check if the request contains a blacklisted URL
    if (strstr(request, BLACKLISTED_URL) != NULL) {
        const char* response = "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\nContent-Length: 19\r\n\r\nAccess Denied: URL blocked\r\n";
        send(client_socket, response, strlen(response), 0);
        close(client_socket);
        return;
    }

    // Create a connection to the target server
    int target_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
    target_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    target_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if (connect(target_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&target_addr, sizeof(target_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error connecting to the target server");
        close(client_socket);
        return;
    }

    // Forward the request to the target server
    send(target_socket, request, bytes_received, 0);

    // Forward the response from the target server to the client
    char response_buffer[4096];
    ssize_t bytes_sent;
    while ((bytes_received = recv(target_socket, response_buffer, sizeof(response_buffer), 0)) > 0) {
        bytes_sent = send(client_socket, response_buffer, bytes_received, 0);
        if (bytes_sent < 0) {
            perror("Error sending response to the client");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Close the sockets
    close(client_socket);
    close(target_socket);
}

int main() {
    int proxy_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in proxy_addr;
    proxy_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    proxy_addr.sin_port = htons(PROXY_PORT);
    proxy_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(proxy_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&proxy_addr, sizeof(proxy_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error binding to the proxy port");
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(proxy_socket, 10) < 0) {
        perror("Error listening on the proxy socket");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Proxy server listening on port %d...\n", PROXY_PORT);

    while (1) {
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        int client_socket = accept(proxy_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);

        if (client_socket < 0) {
            perror("Error accepting client connection");
        } else {
            handle_client(client_socket);
        }
    }

    close(proxy_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the return value of `socket()` ignored? What problem are you facing?

Comment: You have your own web server running on localhost? Because that's where you are connecting to (`"127.0.0.1"`) – or trying at least…

Comment: @Aconcagua yes actually

Comment: @Harith sorry, I am unable to figure out which ignored socket() you are referring to

Comment: @MT16 The very first line in `main()`.

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier, I am actually looking for how to implement the same but for a HTTPS server. Thanks

Comment: One thing I notice: You try to read the client request with one single call to `recv` – while it is pretty *likely* that this will read the entire request at once (most likely contained in a single IP package...) there's actually no *guarantee* for. If you wan to be on the safe side you'd implement a loop here as well and determine by protocol syntax if the entire request has been received.

Comment: Just as a side note: The way you implemented your proxy it remains unresponsive to new requests while still waiting for the reply of a remote server. You might mitigate by maintaining a `std::vector` for the sockets (including both server socket and client sockets) and do a `poll` (linux) or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` (windows) on all of them (alternatively `select`, but that has limited number of sockets to manage). Whichever socket can provide data you'd handle then immediately. Another approach is having one separate thread per each client (I personally prefer the former).

Comment: Apart from, what is your actual question?

Comment: Besides, my main concern is about how to implement for https which deals with an SSL/TLS encryption?

Comment: @Harith haven't I done it correctly, I mean, I need to accept the connection from the client side so for that I have tried creating a proxy socket which connects to the client socket. Could you please describe how it should have been done, if done incorrectly?

Comment: @Aconcagua I actually missed onto considering the point that it might get unresponsive for other incoming requests. I will make the change for sure, thanks!

Comment: Concerning encryption [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267029/example-of-https-client-for-c-application) might be helpful, though haven't evaluated any deeper.

Comment: @Aconcagua I am looking at a possibility where I directly read the IP address from the layer 3 by using a raw socket: socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0). Could you comment on this. Thanks

Comment: @MT16 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064636/getting-the-source-address-of-an-incoming-socket-connection) might be what you are looking for – apart from, if you use UDP sockets (if that's an option for you at all)  you can retrieve the remote address via [`recvfrom`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom), too.